# float rule 6: The outer top of an element's floating box may not be higher than the top of any line-box

Tags: css

I can understand this rule, but after I wrote some examples, I was a little uncertain. XD

> The outer top of an element's floating box may not be higher than the top of any line-box containing a box generated by an element earlier in the source document.

`float` element's outer top higher than the top of `line box` by modifying `margin-top` to negative.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 80px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.mt {
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span> Because you don't know What it means to me Love of my life </span>
  <span>
    Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy?
    <img class="left mt" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="" />
  </span>
  <span
    >Each morning I get up I die a little Can barely stand on my feet Take a
    look in the mirror and cry Lord, what you're doing to me</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose this is only meant to describe the normal float layout mechanism, _without_ any additional properties that could influence the element's position applied.

Comment: @CBroe There are indeed some parts in the specification I read, which I also think are describing concepts, rather than modifying them through other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> float element's outer top higher than the top of line box by modifying margin-top to negative.

That's incorrect. The "outer top" is defined as the top outer edge of the margin box. The `margin-top: -100px;` means that (since the img has 0 borders and padding) the top of the margin box is 100px *below* the top of the content box (i.e. where the image is shown).

Comment: emm, a small mistake, It is `-100px` rather than `100px`.

Comment: @OnlyWick. No mistake. You said `-100px` and so did I.

Comment: `the top of the margin box is 100px`. which `content box`? `div`?

Comment: @OnlyWick The img element. My answer is only referring to the img element for both the content box and the margin box. i.e. The img element's margin box top (aka outer top) is 100px below the img element's content box top.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. set `margin-top`  to negative, lead to element shift up, This is because **the top of the margin box below the top of the content box**.